# jquery chain fadein method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a website banner for the homepage, which fades out and then fades in to the new image. These images are contained within an array and I am using the setInterval method to go through them.

However, I am having problems with the fade aspect. The images are changing, but not with the jquery desired effect.

when I check the console, it displays the following message:

> *$(...).attr(...).fadeIn is not a function.*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var bannerImages = [
    "banner1.jpeg",
    "banner2.jpg",
    "banner3.png"
  ];

  var currentImage = 0;

  // CHANGE THE BANNER IMAGE EVERY 5 SECONDS
  setInterval(function() {
    if (currentImage > bannerImages.length - 1) {
      currentImage = 0;
    }

    $(".banner-img").attr("src", bannerImages[currentImage]).fadeIn();
    currentImage++;
  }, 5000)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="banner">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img src="banner3.png" class="img-responsive center-block banner-img">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: What other information do you need exactly? I have elaborated on the issue a bit more. If you require more information, it would be helpful to mention what exactly. Thanks.

Comment: You cant use chaining like that in jQuery, call the `fadeIn()` function before you try to set the image src: `$(".banner-img").fadeIn().attr("src",bannerImages[currentImage]);`

Comment: @jimmy118 just what a [mcve] calls for. An example that runs on its own, so in your case the HTML and any other applicable code.

Comment: @MasterYoda I am getting the same message when I do it that way. The console says TypeError: $(...).fadeIn is not a function

Comment: @jimmy118 Then you havent set up jQuery correctly. Try adding a jQuery CDN reference to make sure the library is loaded properly. For reference: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: @MasterYoda how embarassing!! You are correct, that was the main issue. This is one of my first couple of projects! Nonetheless thank you for the help. Thank you to everyone else who also took the time out to respond!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't get an error message when testing your code...
For the chain of fade you have to chain fadeOut and FadeIn, triggering fadeIn in the fadeOut callback :

**HTML** (I removed the src in order to have the fadein on the first image) :

```
<section id="banner">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="" class="img-responsive center-block banner-img">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS :**

```
.banner-img { display: none; }
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var bannerImages = [
        "banner1.jpeg",
        "banner2.jpg",
        "banner3.png"
    ];
    var currentImage = 0;

    // First display
    $(".banner-img").attr("src", bannerImages[currentImage++]).fadeIn();

    // CHANGE THE BANNER IMAGE EVERY 5 SECONDS
    setInterval( function() {
        if (currentImage === bannerImages.length) {
            currentImage = 0;
        }
        $(".banner-img").fadeOut(function() {
            $(".banner-img").attr("src", bannerImages[currentImage++]).fadeIn();
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/vgta1rnm/2/**

Answer (score -1):

```js
var $banner = $(".banner-img")
$banner.attr("src",bannerImages[currentImage]);
$banner.fadeIn();
```